# Subtraction of elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, subtraction

I'm fairly new to Java and I'm trying to understand how to subtract elements. I have tried to Googled it but haven't found an answer yet(and I receive the following error message "The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) `int[]`, `double[]`").

Let's say I have the following numbers:

```
String A[] ={"AA", "AB", "AC"};

String B[] = {"BA", "BB", "BC"};

int C[] = {1, 2, 3};  

double D[] = {4.01, 5.02, 6.03};        

int E=0;
```

If I want to subtract C with D and assign it to E (E=C-D) how would I do it?

Comment: [JavaScript and Java are very different languages.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Comment: you cant do this. you can subtract corresponding elements of array but whole array cant be subtracted from other array.

Comment: `E` is an `int` while `C` and `D` are arrays, how do you define a "subtraction" of arrays and how does it produce a single `int` ?

Comment: ok if its possible what answer you expect in `E`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to get a new double array:

```
double E[] = new double[D.length];

for (int i=0; i<D.length; i++) {
    E[i] = (double)C[i] - D[i]; 
}
```

Comment: It's also valid to write the calculation line as either `e[i] = (c[i] - d[i]);` (using the Java naming conventions instead of the original names). The answer's expression makes the widening conversion explicit; the alternate form depends on the rules for binary numeric promotion.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare a new double array and store result of individual subtraction in it.

```
class test1{
    public static void main(String[]args)
        {
        double[] D = {4.01,5.02,6.03};
        int[] C = {1,2,3};
        double[] E = new double[D.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<D.length;i++)
        {
            E[i]=C[i]-D[i];
            System.out.print(" "+E[i]);
        }
    }
}
```